# How to have Unique Message send to Kafka Topic from Producer only once even if we tries to send Multiple times

Tags: c#, .net-core, apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka, and we have .Net core Microservices deployes as Pods in AKS and also using Kafka for communicating between two services.

below is C# code that we use in BackgroundService to pick the failed events from table and publish to topic.

```
await _producer.ProduceAsync(topicName, new Message<string, string> { Key = "{GUID}", Value = {message in JSON} });
```

Issue is when the pod is scale to more that one (let's say pod is scaled to three), each instance is reading the data from table (using EF core) and publish it to topic.

data in topic with same key, repeated three time
[image]

I have Set `ProducerConfig.EnableIdempotence = true` but did not work.

Please help me how can I configure the topic to not to have the same message again even if the application tries to publish it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some misunderstanding. Producer idempotence only applies in the context of **one application** and does not prevent duplicates on the server, only in the context of one bounded transaction of that single client request.

Your scaled replicas do not talk to one another, unless you explicitly write the code to do so. For example, you could use an external KV / document database like Redis / Mongo to write globally unique values, then use tools like Kafka Connect to actually feed the broker from those database events. This pattern is close to the ["Outbox Pattern"](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html)

Alternatively, if you use a compacted Kafka topic **and** build a KTable, then only the latest key will be stored in that table, and the broker will (eventually) automatically drop old keys in prior topic segments.

https://developer.confluent.io/courses/architecture/compaction/